# Selected option doesn't update after variable changes

Tags: angular

I have a particular problem. In a page, a user can press a button in order to change a *maintenance*. This is a complex object that has multiple pairs <key,value>.
I'm trying to figure out a solution that automatically completes fields, so that the user doesn't have to enter again the same values and, potentially, make unwanted changes.

**Current situation**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<ng-template #dialog2 let-ref2="dialogRef2">
  <nb-card>
    <nb-card-header>Modifica Manutenzione</nb-card-header>
    <nb-card-body>
      <label>Macchinario</label>
      <br>
      <nb-select fullWidth id="machine" name="machine" [(ngModel)]="idmachine">
        <nb-option *ngFor="let machine of machineObject" [value]="machine.idmachine"
        [selected]="selectedMaintenance.idmachine == machine.idmachine">
          {{machine.description}}</nb-option>
      </nb-select>
    </nb-card-body>
    <nb-card-footer>
      <button nbButton status="primary" (click)="modifyMaintenance()">Invia</button>
      <button nbButton status="default" (click)="dialogRef2.close()">Chiudi</button>
    </nb-card-footer>
  </nb-card>
</ng-template>
```

Before opening this modal, I have to execute this function:

```
  openDialog2(maintenance): void {
    this.selectedMaintenance = maintenance;
    this.dialogRef2 = this.dialogService.open(this.dialog2);
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

The initial value of *selectedMaintenance* is set to **null**. Before opening the modal, I set a new value to the variable. How can I force Angular to detect this change, so that it automatically selects the appropriate option in the HTML page?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The solution I have found is very simple. Before opening the modal, I assign the values to the variables

```
  openDialog2(maintenance): void {
    this.selectedMaintenance = maintenance;
    this.selectMaintenancesForMachine(this.selectedMaintenance.idmachine);
    this.selectComponentsForMachine(this.selectedMaintenance.idmachine);
    //Assegno le variabili
    this.idmachine = this.selectedMaintenance.idmachine;
    this.machinenumber = this.selectedMaintenance.machinenumber;
    this.dialogRef2 = this.dialogService.open(this.dialog2);
  }
```